# Using full names of chapters in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I have `\chapter[short title]{long title}` because "long title" is too long for a header. However, I want to use "long title" in the table of contents. How can I do this? I'm using report class.

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  
\usepackage{verbatim,a4wide}  
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{arydshln}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{appendix}  
\usepackage{grffile}  
\usepackage{bbm}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{listings}  
\usepackage{chngcntr}  
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{afterpage}  

\usepackage{xpatch}  

\makeatletter  

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%  
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne  
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%  
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%  
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%  
  \else  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%  
  \fi  
}{%  
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne  
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%  
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%  
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\protect\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{#2}}%  
  \else  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{#2}}%  
  \fi  
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}}% Some spacing   afterwards
}{}{}  

\makeatother  



\begin{document}  

\thispagestyle{empty}  
\tableofcontents  

\chapter[short title]{long title}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. We prefer a compilable starter document. The long title does not always really look nice in the ToC. Do you want to have only chapter long titles or all long titles of `\sections` as well?

Comment: Only chapters, sections and subsections are defined without using [].

Comment: The `memoir` class allows three forms of the title: long version, TOC version, and running head version. For `report` one would have to perform some surgery on the definition of `\chapter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible way, patching the `\@chapter` command, that is behind `\chapter` actually and replacing the `#1` in `\addcontentsline` with `#2`. However, this should be done with a top aligning `\parbox`, otherwise the page number would be placed at the end of the paragraph.

There should be a some additional vertical spacing after such a long title chapter entry.

A more sophisticated solution would use another optional argument that holds the long title for the `ToC`.

```
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%
  \else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
  \fi
}{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\protect\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{#2}}%
  \else
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{#2}}%
  \fi
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}}% Some spacing afterwards
}{}{}


\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[Short Title]{This is an awful long title which shouldn't be used actually at all}
\section{ A short section}
\chapter[Short Title]{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** with the OP's. 'MWE'

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}  
\usepackage{verbatim,a4wide}  
\usepackage[cp1250]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[OT4]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[english]{babel}  
\usepackage[section]{placeins}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{arydshln}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{caption}  
\usepackage{subfig}  
\usepackage{appendix}  
\usepackage{grffile}  
\usepackage{bbm}  
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{multirow}  
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{enumitem}  
\usepackage{listings}  
\usepackage{chngcntr}  
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}  
\usepackage{mathtools}  
\usepackage{makeidx}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{afterpage}  


\usepackage{xpatch}  



\makeatletter  

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%  
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne  
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%  
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%  
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}%  
  \else  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%  
  \fi  
}{%  
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne  
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%  
  \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%  
  {\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\texorpdfstring{\protect\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{#2}}{#2}}%  
  \else  
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\parbox[t]{0.9\linewidth}{#2}}{#2}}%  
  \fi  
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}}% Some spacing   afterwards
}{\typeout{Patching was successfull!}}{}  


\usepackage{hyperref}  


\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}  

\thispagestyle{empty}  
\tableofcontents  

\chapter[short title]{Long title}



\end{document}
```

Comment: @magnificop: Well, you did not show any code, so what do you expect me to do now? I don't have a magic chrystal ball that lets me see what you have hidden in your document

Comment: I have edited my question. Now the code is given.

Comment: @magnificop: Yes, of course it doesn't work, because you load `hyperref` before the patching. It's a well-known fact, that `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package (in almost any case!)

Comment: Thank you. Now it works. However, bookmarks look strange, e.g., "[t]0.9long title"

Comment: @magnificop: You need `\texorpdfstring` for the bookmark contents. See my update please