# section to tableofcontents update

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, sections-paragraphs

I'm using the following structure:

```
\section[short chapter]{my long long long long section}
```

I would like to use the long section name in my table of contents, because the short chapter is now used there. Is this possible?

> UPDATE

[image]

My chapter and section overlap in my header, I'm using a fancyhead in a report style. As a solution I found the structure I described above to make a shorter chapter. That resulted in a shorter table of contents line. Now, I want to use the long long long section for my table of contents.

Comment: Welcome, omit the brackets completely.

Comment: Using `section` and `chapter` as terms are confusing here

Comment: @Johannes_B omit the brackets completely: `\section[short chapter] my long long long section` That would leave this? I dont get it, sorry.

Comment: @Pim: No, Johannes_B meant omitting the square brackets `[short chapter]`, not the braces, i.e. `\section{my long long long long section}`, but your question is not really clear, in my point of view

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\section Short Chapter{my long long long section}`. I feel stupid, but to me omitting means deleting. So, I would be left with the above. That isn't working.

Comment: @Pim: I clearified my comment

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My problem is that my chapter and section overlap in my header. So, I was looking for a solution so that they wont overlap. I found the square bracket option. But that resulted in a table of contents that isnt corresponding with the doctitle..

Comment: @Pim: As I stated above: Your question is totally unclear. In the last comment you mention the header problem for the first time, but not in the question itself. Please provide a minimal example that is compilable and that shows your problem. At the moment, this is guess-work only. Providing such an example is usual here, not a single line of code that shows nothing actually

Comment: Either set the toc entry by hand, or the mark by hand: `\section[dancing wombat]{the dancing wombat of NY zoo}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{the dancing wombat of NY zoo}` or `\section{the dancing wombat of NY zoo}\markright{dancing wombat}`.

Comment: On the other hand, i would rather change the header to show just the chapter title. As you see, it soon gets a bit crowded up there.

Comment: Perhaps something like my answer to this question might help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299028/using-full-names-of-chapters-in-table-of-contents

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Are you using any packages that set your `\chapter`s or `\section`s?

Comment: @Werner `\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following might be sufficient for your needs. It provides an additional, optional argument for `\section` that is used for typesetting the header in a similar way to the interface provided by [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir):

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{xpatch}

\let\oldsection\section
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{s o o m}{%
  \markright{}% Clear right mark
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    % \section*
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       % \section*
       {\IfNoValueT{#3}
          % \section*{...}
          {\oldsection*{#4}}
       }
       % \section*[.]
       {\oldsection*{#4}%
       \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}#2}%
       \IfNoValueF{#3}
          % \section*[.][..]{...}
          {\markright{#3}}
       }
    }
    % \section
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       % \section
       {\oldsection{#4}}
       % \section[.]
       {\oldsection[#2]{#4}
        \IfNoValueF{#3}
          % \section[.][..]{...}
          {\markright{#3}}
       }
    }
}

\pagestyle{headings}
\sloppy% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section[ToC entry][Header entry]{Another section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section*{A starred section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\section*[Starred ToC section]{Another starred section}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

You can use

```
\section[*][<ToC>][<header>]{<title>}
```

Of course, some conditioning is not necessary, as you can't have only the *second* optional argument and not the first (using the default `[`..`]` notation).

Comment: I would suggest to use the 'header' optional argument after the mandatory one -- I find two optional arguments always difficult to remember which one stands for which purpose.

Comment: Doing as Christian Hupfer suggested (`somo` as argument definition with the last `o` for the TOC entry) the author would not need to adjust any `\section` in his document.

Comment: There would most likely be a change required for the sections where the header should be different than the ToC entry anyway. My answer doesn't require the user to make any changes to their sectional commands unless this is the case (since the header-argument is optional).

Comment: But the header argument is the second optional one. So the first one, which is already set in the authors document, won't apply to the heading but to the TOC entry. This is not what the author is looking for, but the changes needed to your given solution are marginal.

Answer (score 3):

As Johannes_B mentioned, you should try something like this in the preamble:

```
\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand{\section}[2][]{\oldsection{#2}\def\currentheading{#1}}
```

The optional argument will be stored in `\currentheading` instead and the "default" `\section{}` will be executed with the long title only. Replace `\currentheading` by whatever you need to achieve the heading you want.

Edit: to be aware of \section* you should use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldsection\section
\def\currentheading{}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
  {\oldsection*{#3}}%
  {\oldsection{#3}}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}%
  {\def\currentheading{#2}}%
  {}%
}

\begin{document}


\section[head]{foo}
\section[overwritten]{bar}
\section*{buz}
The current heading should be overwritten ... it is \currentheading.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, this is not really what Johannes_B mentioned. And you will get into troubles with `\section*{Foo}` versions (like being used in `\tableofcontents` etc.)

Comment: Would `\usepackage{xparse}` and `\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{sO{}m}{\IfBooleanTF#1{\oldsection*{#3}}{\oldsection{#3}}\def\currentheading{#2}\currentheading}` fix this? I'm no low-level tex user ...

Comment: Well, yes. I suggest to catch the optional argument with `som` and `\IfValueTF{#2}{...}{...}` but I leave it to you.

Comment: You can use `\IfValueT{#2}{...}` here if you just want to provide for the `true` branch (as is done in your example), but I suggest to provide a compilable version, not just fragments, otherwise this post will get to the *Low Quality Review Queue* very quickly ;-)

Comment: Gern geschehen :-P